# How to show data with less than current date in yii?

Tags: php, yii

How do i filter the date which is less than the current date?

```
Company::model()->with(array(
            'Bundles'=>array(
                'condition'=>'Bundles.status=1',
                'order'=>'payment_date DESC',
            ),
        ))->findByPk($company_id);
```

Currently above code is displaying all data whose `status = 1`

but i want to show the data whose `expiry_date` should be less than current date. How can i achieve this?

This is what i have tried so far but NO success.

```
Company::model()->with(array(
            'Bundles'=>array(
                'condition'=>'Bundles.expiry_date < date("Y-m-d H:i:s")',
                'order'=>'payment_date DESC'
            ),
        ))->findByPk($company_id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
Company::model()->with(array(
            'Bundles'=>array(
                'condition'=>'Bundles.expiry_date < CURDATE()',
                'order'=>'payment_date DESC'
            ),
        ))->findByPk($company_id);
```

You cannot put php date function into SQL statement in the way u did it. Try to use `CURDATE()`